# Custom c# code in a Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I am populating a report using an Object. Everything works fine, if my members are string, however, I have a few members, which are `List<string>`.

When I add these fields to the report (in designer, visual studio 2012) and run the report, they show as

> '#Error'

Viewing the properties of the report, I can see that there is a 'custom code' tab, for which I've entered the following method to convert the list of strings into a array of string.

```
public string[] GetListItems(List<string> intList)
{
    var s = intList.ToArray();
    return s;
}
```

Then when I try and replace the field with an expression and enter the following:

```
=Join(Code.GetListItems(Fields!Aka.Value),",")
```

and then run the report, VS fails to build with the following:

> Error 2   The Value expression for the textrun ‘Aka.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30456] 'GetListItems' is not a member of 'ReportExprHostImpl.CustomCodeProxy'.
>
> Error 1   There is an error on line 0 of custom code: [BC30183] Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

Can anyone shed any light why this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is C# code. Directly in the report you can only use Visual Basic. C# is avaliable as an external DLL.

Comment: Hi sdrzymala, do you happen to know said DLL. I'd prefer not to mix VB/C#

Comment: In the SSRS you can use C# or VB, but directly in the Report Properties Code you can use just VB. If you want to use C# than you need to write your own custom DLL, register and use as a funtion. If you have your own DLL you don't have to add anything in your Report Properties code you can just invoke your funtion in any SSRS expression,.

Answer (score 0):

For those who can't create go through the difficulties of implementing a third-party DLL. A simpler; but, a messier solution is as follows.

To summarize solution, you can create properties that returns a value that the reports can easily work with.

In my scenario, I had 2 classes:

```
public class Parent {
    public Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The type that I was binding to my Report was Parent; however, I needed to access the Name property inside Child. In otherwords I needed to do:

```
Parent.Child.Name
```

This where I ran into the same problem that the OP ran into. Due to the scope of my project (a college project), I can't bother with third-party dlls or writing my own dll...

So what I did is add more properties to the `Parent` class.

```
public class Parent {
    public Child { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get => Child.Name; }
}

public class Child {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

By adding an additional property to `Parent` that has an type that Reports can work with, I can now easily access the `Child`'s Name through my `Parent`class.

Of course this is messy; but, I'm in a situation where I can't go with the more complicated/time consuming dlls solution.

I just hope my instructors will allow this solution without penalty...

Answer (score -1):

If you just created a report and showing an error code like 
BC30016 labels are not valid outside of the method. 
The reson in my case was that i have insert the random numerical value n the code property of a report1.rdlc
Hence to solve this type of error, goto report properties and remove the value from the code.

Comment: Heya, thanks for sharing your solution. However, it seems to be the answer to a *different* question. You could consider asking the question *you* had and answering it yourself, if you want to share with others.